# How to display different views on same window using perspective in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, perspective

I have created two user's windows and one main window which will contain menu bar, tool bar and status bar at bottom.
Now I want to display two user's windows either on main window or menu bar, tool bar then both user window and then status bar on bottom.
All this  I need to show on launch of application on one window(Workbench) .
I have added image as a reference.
I know about perspective factory but don't know how to use it like how to write its **.XML** file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perspectives are part of Eclipse RCP. If you are writing an SWT program (not an RCP) you can't use them.

Comment: how can i show 2-3 views together on launch of application and also view will not dispose till application closed?

Comment: First of all you need to make it clear what you are writing. Is this an Eclipse RCP or an Eclipse plugin or a SWT application?

Answer (score 0):

To use this feature, first open the workspace that contains your customised layout. Then select File > Switch Workspace > Other… which will open a dialog prompting you for an existing/new workspace. Select the workspace, then click the Copy Settings collapsible section. Select the Workbench Layout checkbox and click Ok. Your workspace will open and should reflect the customised layout of the previous workspace.